# PHP Selenium chromedriver finaliza sessão após efetuar login sem erro aparente;

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, warnings

Ao finalizar o input dos dados do login via selenium o robo clica em login, a sessão é derrubada em pontos diferentes, as vezes antes de entrar na tela de cadastro, as vezes após o login e outras vezes ele consegue entrar na tela de cadastro e a sessão não é finalizada, ocorre tudo normalmente. Devido isso acredito que o problema não esteja no código do robo, mas sim em alguma configuaração do chromedriver ou do selenium que derrubam a sessão segundo o log que aparece no CMD:

```
sion@66c9d0aa
13:15:41.230 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element/0.
9466039730741942-5/click (handler: ServicedSession)
13:15:41.233 INFO - To upstream:
13:15:41.367 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":null}
13:15:45.268 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:15:45.268 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing GET on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/alert_text
(handler: ServicedSession)
13:15:45.283 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":27,"value":{"message":"no such alert\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3
770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76
e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_6
4)"}}
13:15:50.333 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:15:50.333 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:15:50.333 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder
1_DataListMenu_ctl00_LinkButton2"}
13:15:50.365 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.9876733147422252-1"}}
13:15:50.411 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:15:50.427 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/moveto (ha
ndler: ServicedSession)
13:15:50.427 INFO - To upstream: {"element":"0.9876733147422252-1"}
13:15:50.474 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":null}
13:15:50.525 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:15:50.525 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element/0.
9876733147422252-1/click (handler: ServicedSession)
13:15:50.525 INFO - To upstream:
13:15:51.239 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":null}
13:16:01.294 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:01.294 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing GET on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/alert_text
(handler: ServicedSession)
13:16:01.325 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":27,"value":{"message":"no such alert\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3
770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76
e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_6
4)"}}
13:16:01.359 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:01.390 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/url (handl
er: ServicedSession)
13:16:01.390 INFO - To upstream: {"url":"https:\/\/panconsig.pansolucoes.com.br\
/WebAutorizador\/MenuWeb\/Cadastro\/Proposta\/UI.PropostaSimplificada.aspx"}
13:16:03.424 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":null}
13:16:03.476 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:03.477 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:03.481 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:03.750 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:04.799 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:04.801 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:04.805 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:04.827 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:05.868 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:05.868 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:05.890 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:05.913 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:06.961 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:06.963 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:06.967 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:06.988 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:08.034 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:08.035 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:08.039 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:08.060 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:09.120 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:09.122 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:09.131 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:09.153 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:10.199 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:10.201 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:10.205 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:10.226 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:11.283 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:11.288 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:11.292 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:11.313 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:12.359 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:12.360 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:12.370 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:12.388 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:13.449 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:13.450 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:13.454 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:13.497 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:14.544 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:14.546 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:14.549 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:14.571 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:15.616 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:15.620 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:15.626 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:15.657 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:16.703 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:16.704 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:16.708 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:16.723 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:17.770 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:17.772 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:17.776 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:17.797 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:18.837 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:18.837 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:18.852 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:18.879 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:19.931 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:19.933 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:19.937 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:19.961 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:21.009 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:21.013 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:21.018 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:21.038 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:22.086 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:22.088 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:22.091 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:22.112 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:23.165 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:23.170 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing POST on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b/element (h
andler: ServicedSession)
13:16:23.176 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"btnConfirmar_txt"}
13:16:23.198 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"
method\":\"id\",\"selector\":\"btnConfirmar_txt\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0
.3770.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa
76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86
_64)"}}
13:16:24.256 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSes
sion@66c9d0aa
13:16:24.259 INFO - Handler thread for session 01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b
(chrome): Executing DELETE on /session/01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0b (handler
: ServicedSession)
13:16:24.303 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"01d56e8f47777e8d3e8b8716b93e2d0
b","status":0,"value":null}
13:16:24.318 INFO - Removing session org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedS
ession@66c9d0aa
13:16:24.381 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"","status":0,"value":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontramos o real problema. No código do robo a url de destino estava errada, após mudarmos essa url o problema parou de ocorrer.